# How to restrict oracle table to have limited records

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can anyone please help me if we can have any restrictions on oracle table to hold maximum of 20k records, if anyone tries to insert beyond 20k records it should throw an error. I could think here of dB triggers, any suggestions pls??

Comment: Either you can have a trigger, or check the # of records before insert and make the decision, or if the table has an identity column, use that to let it be inserted or throw an error

Comment: What is the business problem you are trying to solve?  This seems like a very random requirement.

Answer (score 1):

**Trigger** is definitively not suitable for such tasks. Trigger is *not supposed to enforce integrity*. Why?

If two users insert that *last allowed row*, both triggers succeed as they check against *commited data*.

For maintaining integrity the **check constraints** were designed.

In your case (simplified to three rows allowed) it would be

```
create table tab
(id INT primary key check (id between 1 and 3));

insert into tab(id) values(1);
insert into tab(id) values(2);
insert into tab(id) values(3);
insert into tab(id) values(4);
ORA-02290: check constraint (REPORTER.SYS_C0011024) violated
```

You may add automatic key assignment using sequence or identity column.